# Off-topic WTF? This has to be a mistake

Tags: discussion, off-topic

How can asking [how to register a domain](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/7375/how-to-register-a-domain-for-a-beginner?rq=1) be in-topic, but asking about [domain registration stats](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/44463/is-there-any-data-about-how-many-tlds-are-registered-and-renewed-every-day) be off-topic? It makes no sense!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you for bringing this question to Meta.

From the [Pro Webmasters FAQ](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq):

> If your question generally covers the operation of websites which you
>   control, then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

Statistics on domain registration are outside the scope of this site.

In the interest of helping you find an answer, there are a number of sites like [WebHosting.info](http://www.webhosting.info/domains/country_stats/) and [DailyChanges.com](http://www.dailychanges.com/) (disclaimer: I am a former employee of a DomainTools.com subsidiary) - and ARIN operates an [rWHOIS API](http://whois.arin.net/ui) which you may find useful (though bulk querying is discouraged).

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated!